# Windows 10 Pip No Output

Tags: python, pip

I have installed pip on my Windows 10 laptop the same way I have been doing for the past few years (via `python -m pip install -U pip setuptools`). The weird part is, on my laptop, Pip causes no output. It just causes a blank line. For example

```
C:\Users\...> pip install hvjkdfghfdkghdkgf

C:\Users\...>
```

When it should throw an error that the module *hvjkdfghfdkghdkgf* does not exist.

I have read that you must edit the configuration file, but when I checked where the configuration file should be, there was none to be found. I tried creating the configuration file, and there was no change (I do not remember where, as this was over a month ago, sorry).

I have tried `pip install ___ -v`, and `pip install ___ --verbose` as found on the pip website: https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/#install-pip-setuptools-and-wheel, and still no luck.

Thanks in advance.

[EDIT]

By the way, It still installs modules, I just want to be able to see the progress of the installation, and if the module was even found.

Comment: what python and pip version where you had the problem?

Comment: Could you move your solution to an answer instead of part of the question? This way it gets marked as resolved (and I think you get rep for it)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I uninstalled pip:

```
python -m pip uninstall pip setuptools
```

And then followed the instructions here:
https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/#do-i-need-to-install-pip

By first downloading *setup.py* from https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py, and running `> python get-pip.py` in the command line in the directory where the python file is saved.

Thanks anyways.

Comment: The part that was relevant for me: "and running > python get-pip.py in the command line in the directory **where the python file is saved**." I had been running *get-pip.py* with IDLE, which seemed to work correctly but resulted in pip having no output and not installing anything.

Running *python get-pip.py* in the correct directory uninstalled, then reinstalled, the same version of pip.