# PIP does nothing on windows 11

Tags: python, pip, windows-11

I tried to install any package using PIP but nothing happens, I dont get any error or something like that, just nothing happend, look the images, what could happend here i don't know what to do.

[image]

[image]

Someone here have the same problem?

Comment: [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47313426/windows-10-pip-no-output) may be relevant.

Comment: unfortunately  that methods not work for me :( still nothing happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I not sure why happend this, but this is the way i solve it.

First I uninstall the win32 python version then I install the last python version from the Microsoft Store as windows App and uninstall it finally reinstall the win32 python version and now works.